# Shorts, longs BTC data

Tags: exchanges, api, historical-trade-data, bitfinex, margin

I am trying to use the Bitfinex API to get historic shorts,longs BTC/USD data.So, the Bitfinex gives size data with Available values: '1m', this equals last 2 hours, i need last two month at least. Trading view have all data, but i must pass the license. Have another ways to get this data?

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly common for exchanges to only provide a limited amount of historical data. Tradingview and  other sites that have more historical data store it themselves on a database. With 2 hours of data you could ping the exchange API once every 2 hours adding the new data to your database each time.